# Noise floor of an unmatched resistive network thru PSD calculations

Tags: resistors, noise, thermal, noisefloor, psd

I am modeling the PSD of various loads to calculate noise floors. I have various load terminations from 25 ohms to 250 ohms.

Per Johnson-Nyquist, the noise floor on a resistor when load and source are matched, let's say 50 ohms, you get PSD of about -174 dBm/Hz for 300K.

How could one calculate this when the termination is 25 ohms, and you still have a 50 ohms load (such as a spectrum analyzer input)?